# expm1 for GNU gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, exp

Is there any way to call a fast implementation of expm1  from GNU Fortran? 
Ideally, it would be great to have a function to calculate (exp(x)-1)/x directly to avoid extra check for zero argument. 
Elemental version of expm1 would be especially helpful.

Comment: :)) It is not the problem of writing it. It is written and works. The issue is to have it fast when you have to calculate billions of them. There is a reason why  math libraries (e.g. libm) do have separate implementations for exp and  expm1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it's called from libm:

```
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_double

  implicit none

  interface
     real(c_double) function expm1(x) bind(c, name='expm1')
       import c_double
       real(c_double), intent(in), value :: x
     end function expm1
  end interface

  print*, expm1(3.4d0)

end program
```

If the glibc source code for the function does not look too discouraging then you might wish to translate it into Fortran in order to make it elemental (if by elemental you meant the Fortran keyword).

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense.  I'll play with it to see how much of performance can i get out of it. I wonder if gsl implementation is by any means faster than libm....

Comment: UPD: No, judging from the gsl source code, it is not...